# NullPointerException during launching testng xml with groups

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc, testng

I have one very unpleasant problem with TestNG. NullPointerException occurs while I trying to launch some of my tests with groups which I assigned to them.

Examples of tests:

```
public class DemonstrationTest01 extends FundamentalTest {

    private static final String LOGIN = "Fruzenshtein";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "111111";

    @Test(priority=1, groups="foo")
    public void test01() throws InterruptedException {
        basePage.logIn(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
            .checkTextPresent("Welcome, "+LOGIN+"!")
            .clickSiteLogo()
            .checkTextPresent("Welcome, "+LOGIN+"!")
            .logOut();

    }

}
```

Second test:

```
public class DemonstrationTest03 extends FundamentalTest {

    @Test(priority=1, groups="foo")
    public void test03() throws InterruptedException {
        ProductPage productPage = basePage.navToCategory("Homewear")
            .checkCategoryTitle("Mugs")
            .navToProductPage(2)
            .checkTextPresent("0 items")
            .addToCart()
            .checkTextPresent("1 items");

        Assert.assertEquals(basePage.getShoppingCartTotal(), productPage.getProductPrice());

        productPage.addToCart()
            .checkTextPresent("2 items");

        Assert.assertEquals(basePage.getShoppingCartTotal(), 2*productPage.getProductPrice());
    }

}
```

Here is an FundamentalTest:

```
public class FundamentalTest {

    protected BasePage basePage;

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({ "testServer" })
    public void init(String testServer) {
        basePage = PageFactory.initElements(new FirefoxDriver(), BasePage.class);
        basePage.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        basePage.driver.get(testServer);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void destruct() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        basePage.driver.close();
    }

}
```

And in the end my xml launcher:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SingleTestSuite" >
  <parameter name="testServer"  value="https://shop.shakhtar.com/en/"/>
  <test name="StandAloneTest">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="foo"></include>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="com.shakhtar.qa.tests" />        
    </packages>         
  </test>      
</suite>
```

What can be the reason of the NullPointerException? And how can I fix it? Here is a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29572172/Shakhtar.rar) on my project.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: If you have a **NullPointerException** in you title, have it in your question aswell...

Comment: Where exactly does the NullPointerException is being thrown? Is it within the TestNG invocation or in one of your classes? And the stack trace would really help.

Answer (score 5):

Just Add (alwaysRun = true) to the @BeforeClass annotation.

So your fundamental class should look like -:

public class FundamentalTest {

```
protected BasePage basePage;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "testServer" })
public void init(String testServer) {
    basePage = PageFactory.initElements(new FirefoxDriver(), BasePage.class);
    basePage.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    basePage.driver.get(testServer);
}

@AfterClass
public void destruct() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    basePage.driver.close();
}
```

}

Thanks alot,this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with your `Function_Library(FundamentalTest)` which you need to run first before accessing the methods.